# How to check if an array is empty in OPA Rego

Tags: arrays, null, is-empty, opa, rego

I have an array which declare like this- `arr = []`.
I want to check it it's empty.
I tried: `count(arr)==0`, `is_null(arr)`, `arr==[]` and `arr==""`.

Comment: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/QZPDfOoa5A  count(arr)==0 and arr==[] works fine

Answer (score 3):

Using `count` would be the the idiomatic way:

```
arr_is_empty {
    count(arr) == 0
}
```